# Angular routing with query param not working

Tags: angular

```
{ path: 'CrossLaunch/:id', component: CrossLaunchComponent,  pathMatch: 'full' },
```

I tried to run my app on http://localhost:4005/CrossLaunch/1 and console giving below error Why?

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4005/CrossLaunch/assets/font/Montserrat-Medium.ttf' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
1:25 GET http://localhost:4005/CrossLaunch/assets/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
1:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4005/CrossLaunch/assets/video/video-js.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
1:26 GET http://localhost:4005/CrossLaunch/assets/jquery/jquery.json-2.4.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
1:29 GET http://localhost:4005/CrossLaunch/assets/xmpp/xmppvideoroom.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
1:30 GET http://localhost:4005/CrossLaunch/assets/jitsi-external/jitsi-external-api.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
1:31 GET http://localhost:4005/CrossLaunch/assets/strophe.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
1:32 GET http://localhost:4005/CrossLaunch/assets/xmpp/strophe.disco.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
1:33 GET http://localhost:4005/CrossLaunch/assets/xmpp/strophe.jingle.sdp.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
1:34 GET http://localhost:4005/CrossLaunch/assets/xmpp/request.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
1:54 GET http://localhost:4005/CrossLaunch/assets/video/video.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
1:56 GET http://localhost:4005/CrossLaunch/assets/viewer.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
61:121 GET http://localhost:4005/CrossLaunch/runtime.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: That is because your hosting server is rejection to serve files. if you check probably it is returning internally and HTML file instead of your font file detailing the error

Comment: Or your application is not where your web server is looking